# Set default theme Keycloak 17

Tags: keycloak

I´m migrating to Keycloak 17 but I´m struggling with the custom themes.

On my previous version (16.1.1) I was able to set the default theme with the `KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME` env variable, which pointed to my custom theme.

Now i´m still able to load the themes correctly (They appear on the web console), but v17 it´s not responding to this env.

I found a way to set up the welcome theme on startup with:

```
kc.sh start --spi-theme-welcome-theme=custom
```

but this option doesn´t work for other kind of themes like login or admin.

Is there any other env or flag that i can use on startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use it via ENV, but you have to set `KC_SPI_THEME_DEFAULT`. Additionally, you may have to start Keycloak with the `--auto-build` option.

Comment: Thanks! For me it worked without the --auto-build

Answer (score 2):

If you start your server with `kc.sh start --spi-theme-default=custom-theme`, then it should use the supplied custom theme, according to: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bfce612641a70e106b20b136431f0e4046b5c37f/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/theme/DefaultThemeManager.java#L57

This worked for me with Keycloak 18.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem, in the end I set custom theme to each realm manually.